# Removing reapeated numbers from a list, any recomendations?

Tags: python-3.x

So, I just managed to finish a problem that was proposed to me, and I find it very difficult since I started learning looping with `for` and using **lists** recently, I thought about sharing the problem and my solution with you guys so you could give me some advice on how I should make my code better or different ways to solve the problem, hopefully you guys can help me, thank you for your attention and sorry if I made some mistakes, I am new to stackoverflow and programming.

***Question***

**Write a function that receives a list with natural numbers, verify if such list has repeated numbers, if so remove them. The function should return a correspondent list with no repeated elements. The list should be returned in ascending order.**

```
def remove_repeated_numbers(z):
    x = 1
    for i in z:
        y = x
        while y <= (len(z) - 1):
            if i == z[y]:
                del z[y]
                y = (y - 1)              #Once z[y] is deleted, should check same spot again
            y = (y + 1)
        x = (x + 1)
    list_finished = sorted(z[:])
    return list_finished
```

```
def main():
    run = True
    z = []
    while run:
        u = int(input("Entry value: "))
        if u != 0:
            z.append(u)
        else:
            run = False
    print(remove_repeated_numbers(z))
```

```
main()
```

Comment: Are you forbidden to use `set`? Because the canonical solution is a one-liner, `return sorted(set(z))`; `set` deduplicates (but imposes arbitrary and largely useless ordering), `sorted` then converts back to a sorted `list`.

Comment: If you have working code that you're looking to have peer-reviewed, you should ask on [codereview.se] instead - it was created just for that purpose. Make sure you read and understand their [site guidelines](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before posting there. This site is for questions about specific problems you're having with code or use of a programmer's tool.